# ASP.NET MVC web application inside a webforms web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

We are thinking about building new pages in our webforms based website.

We ask ourselves if we can build the new pages using ASP.NET MVC but we don't want the user to feel the change when entering those pages.

The previous login will be available to the MVC, so the user won't have to type his login again, and the same goes for the session - same session will be use for both sites.

P.S.  We are using asp.net framework 4.5

Can it be done??

Comment: [Yep](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx).

Comment: can you post some references for frothier reading?
it w'd be nice to see an example project with this structure